# um programa que leia 30 pares de valores inteiros, armazenando o menor valor em uma variável x e o maior em y

Tags: c

alguem pode me ajudar a desenvolver esse problema?

Apresente um programa que leia 30 pares de valores inteiros, armazenando o
menor valor em uma variável x e o maior em y, e para cada par de valores, calcular a soma
dos inteiros de x até y, inclusive.
até agora consegui fazer até aqui:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int v[30];
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int soma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
                scanf("%d", &v[i]);
                if (v[i]>y) {
                    y = v[i];
                } else {
                    x = v[i];
                }
        }
            
    printf("\nVetor: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
    {
        printf("[%d]\n", v[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

alguem pode me dar uma luz de como devo fazer "para cada par de valores, calcular a soma
dos inteiros de x até y, inclusive.", não estou conseguindo entender exatamente. consegui pegar o maior e menor, no entanto, não esta pegando o maior e menor dos pares como por exemplo: v[0] e v[1], v[2] e v[3] e assim sucessivamente, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu entendi este problema de maneira um pouco diferente:

> um programa que leia 30 pares de valores inteiros

Ou seja, o programa deve ler um par de valores inteiros (a, b) 30 vezes. Abaixo está minha solução, com comentários para cada passo.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    
    // Fazemos leitura e cálculo das entradas 30 vezes
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
        int a, b, soma = 0;
        
        // Primeiro, lemos um par de números
        printf("Primeiro número : ");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("Segundo número : ");
        scanf("%d", &b);
        
        // Segundo, armazenamos esses números em variáveis x, y: x para o menor número, y para o maior
        int x = a > b ? b : a;
        int y = a < b ? b : a;
        printf("(x, y) = (%d, %d)\n", x, y);
        
        // Terceiro, fazmos a soma de todos os inteiros de x até y (incluindo x e y)
        while (x <= y) {
            soma += x;
            x++;
        }
        printf("Soma: %d\n", soma);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ultima duvida, quando vc utiliza "? b : a", o que significa?

Comment: essa foi a única parte que não entendi, na hora em que utiliza: "int x = a > b ? b : a;", nunca havia utilizado desta forma.

Comment: @natalia Este operador é chamado *operador ternário* e podemos ler da seguinte forma `x ? y : z`, onde `x` indica uma certa *condição* (`a > b`, por exemplo), e, se a condição em `x` for verdadeira, então `y` é executada, caso contrário `z` é executada. Basicamente, funciona como uma forma simplificada de *if/else* e o resultado da operação pode ser utilizado em uma atribuição de valor. Portanto, no caso desse código, `int x = a > b ? b : a` podemos interpretar como *declare e insira o valor de b, caso a é maior que b ou o valor de a caso contrário* ou *atribua a x o menor valor entre a e b*.